# mvpa2: restore SOM from Kohonen layer

Tags: python, som

I'm trying to implement self-organising maps in Python using [pymvpa2 SOM mapper](http://www.pymvpa.org/generated/mvpa2.mappers.som.Mapper.html).

It works just fine, but how do I save the resulting SOM?


h5save didn't work for me and I started wondering, if I can create an empty SOM instance and then attach a saved Kohonen layer to it? However, when I try to feed the Kohonen matrix to an empty mapper I get this error:

```
...
size = (15,15)
som_new = SimpleSOMMapper(size, 1900, learning_rate=0.05)
som_new.K = som_trained.K
>> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `som.K` but if you look into `som.py` from the package you'll see that the script uses `som._K` to modify Kohonen layers.

Use this approach:

```
som_new.is_trained = True
som_new._K = som_trained.K
```

And then you'll have your map transferred to an empty mapper. But be careful as `som.py` doesn't check what you add to the Kohonen layer this way: it can be a string, an int or whatever.

Comment: Figured I should respond to myself, since I've found the answer